# Need to repaint the ceiling, but what is this original layer?

Tags: ceiling, painting

I need to repaint ceiling in a 50-year old apartment.

Since there were already 2-3 layers of paint on the ceiling, I decided to remove the old paint first. It got removed pretty easy with a scratcher tool. The paint was practically just falling off the ceiling, as if it was not "glued" to the undercoat. I wonder if previous owners even used the paint undercoat (*sous-couche*).

Under the paint there is this super-smooth layer of something I do not recnognize and that does not come off that easily with sanding paper.

In the picture below you can see layers of paint and the super-smooth (unknown) undercoat. **Is this some kind of an oil paint?**

[image: Ceiling]

In the living room I decided not to take any chances, so I removed the unknown layer with a sanding paper (G40) and it wasn't easy! Under this layer there was another (thin) layer of something that looked like a plaster and it got removed almost instantly after the *unknown* layer was removed by the sanding paper.

When I tried to put a layer of plaster over this unknown layer, it soon became very *sticky* while I was laying plaster over it.

**Any recommandations what should I do with it - should I sand it away (hate to do so..) or put a layer of plaster or some specialized wall coating?** (I used "Kit Enduit Magic" by Toupret in the past, but I do not know what is it made off).

Thanks!!

Comment: Your general location might matter.  Certain words in your question might infer a European or Quebec location.  50 years might also before lead paint bans, so sanding is more problematic(testing, more safety).

Comment: Unless the picture is in major zoom, it looks plaster/drywall mud like coating/s.

Comment: @crip659 The location is France. However, it does not look like a layer from 50 years ago. Sorry for not putting some object to give perspective! If the layer is "plaster/drywall mud like coating", then putting another layer of plaster (gypsum) over it should stick to that layer, right?

Comment: In the bathroom I found what seemed to be an original (50 years old) layer of oil paint. That one was a nightmare to take off! Nothing worked - the roughest sanding paper, torching the damn thing at 1500+ C, scratching it etc.. I managed to take it off with an angle grinder and a metal brush, and even that was super difficult. The layer in question however does not get off easily, but compared to the bathroom paint it is a childs play. Considering all this, the unknown layer might not be the oil paint? I'm asking this because the easiest for me would be to put another layer of plaster over it.

Comment: I wonder how do they get the "plaster/drywall mud like coating" to be that super-smooth. I plastered walls before with gypsum, and brushing it even with finest sanding paper (G680) does not get even close to smoothness of the unknown layer. I guess it might be some special mixture, something like the "Kit Enduit Magic" that I used, and not raw gypsum that I usually use for plastering.

Comment: That is the difference between a master and someone who only does it once in a while.  It might also be something completely different.